# asp.net core 2.2 api json file size

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to post large list of data to my API

```
        [HttpPost]
        [RequestSizeLimit(40000000)]
        [Route("PostList")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostList([FromBody] IEnumerable<ItemMasterDto> data)
        {
            // Do work
            return Ok();
        }
```

Sample data to post is like

```
[
  {
    "ExternalMappingId": "I-01",
    "GroupName": "string",
    "SubGroupName": "string",
    "DisplayItemCode": "string",
    "ItemDescription": "string",
    "DispItemDescription": "string",
    "ItemSubDescription": "string",
    "UnitSet": "string",
    "DefaultTranUnitCode": "string",
    "DefaultReportUnitCode": "string",
    "IsVatExempted": true,
    "IsImported": true,
    "IsVATApplicable": true,
    "IsSaleable": true,
    "HSCode": "string",
    "VATPercent": 0,
    "IsManufacturing": true
  }
  {
    "ExternalMappingId": "I-02",
    "GroupName": "string",
    "SubGroupName": "string",
    "DisplayItemCode": "string",
    "ItemDescription": "string",
    "DispItemDescription": "string",
    "ItemSubDescription": "string",
    "UnitSet": "string",
    "DefaultTranUnitCode": "string",
    "DefaultReportUnitCode": "string",
    "IsVatExempted": true,
    "IsImported": true,
    "IsVATApplicable": true,
    "IsSaleable": true,
    "HSCode": "string",
    "VATPercent": 0,
    "IsManufacturing": true
  }
]
```

It work fine with small set of data but when I try to post more then 100k data API refuse the connection and i get call failed with status code 404 (not found) Error. As you can see i already tried `[RequestSizeLimit(40000000)` and i also tried following in my Startup.cs

```
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.BufferBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
            });
```

My total data can be between 100k to 200k. What can i do ?? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Did you try removing request size limit and all that extra configuration from startup file ?

Comment: Yes.. I already did

Comment: I am sure there is no problem with file size but with this parameter IEnumerable<ItemMasterDto>. Try to post sample data as well

Comment: I edited my question and add sample data. Please check . thanks

Comment: IEnumerable<ItemMasterDto> instead try List<ItemMasterDto>.

Comment: What is the 100k you said? Is his unit of measurement KB? Make sure that your json does not exceed the limit . And your settings in startup.cs is for form not the json , you could refer to [here](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/) about increasing file upload size in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @XueliChen what i mean is 100k rows of SQL data. when i test with 10/100/1000 rows of SQL data it works fine but have problem when data volume is 100k.

Comment: this link might help [maxsize input api](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Fail to  reproduce your issue , but I choose the application name not the IIS Express to debug and get the **500** error when the size of json is more than the value set in [RequestSizeLimit] attribute.Make sure that the size of 100k rows data don't exceed the limit value .

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your config file `requestLimits`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 50MB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
   ...
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```